How to unify the result of three queries into one keeping the order given by order by in Django
I am trying to get a list from a model to show the results ordered by status, for example: first "active", then "in progress" and "not active" at the bottom of the list. At the same time the results for each status must be ordered by the date.
I am using Django version 4.0 and MySQL database.
I tried to implement this using Union, but the results are not being ordered correctly.
Here is the Model code:
class LegalDocument(CreateAndUpdateDatesModel):
    class DocumentStatus(models.TextChoices):
        ACTIVE = 'Activo', 'Activo'
        EXPIRED = 'Vencido', 'Vencido'
        EVALUATING = 'Evaluación', 'Evaluación'
        REJECTED = 'Rescindido', 'Rescindido'
        RESOLVED = 'Resuelto', 'Resuelto'

    class DocumentType(models.TextChoices):
        CONTRACT = 'Contrato', 'Contrato'
        AGREEMENT = 'Convenio', 'Convenio'
        MEMORANDUM = 'Memorándum', 'Memorándum'
        ADDENDUM = 'Enmienda', 'Enmienda'
        LETTER = 'Carta', 'Carta'
        OTHER = 'Otro', 'Otro'

    document_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = RichTextUploadingField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DocumentStatus.choices, default=DocumentStatus.ACTIVE)
    expiration_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

And here is how I am implenting the query with union:
legal_documents = LegalDocument.objects.all()

active_documents = legal_documents.filter(status=LegalDocument.DocumentStatus.ACTIVE).order_by('expiration_date')
evaluating_document = legal_documents.filter(status=LegalDocument.DocumentStatus.EVALUATING).order_by('expiration_date')
expired_documents = legal_documents.filter(status=LegalDocument.DocumentStatus.EXPIRED).order_by('expiration_date')
rejected_documents = legal_documents.filter(status=LegalDocument.DocumentStatus.REJECTED).order_by('expiration_date')
resolved_documents = legal_documents.filter(status=LegalDocument.DocumentStatus.RESOLVED).order_by('expiration_date')

legal_documents = active_documents.union(evaluating_document, expired_documents, rejected_documents, resolved_documents, all=True)

The result I am getting, please pay attention to "Expiration Date" column (dates are in format %Y-%m-%d):



Title
Status
Expiration Date




Document1
Activo
2024-10-13


Document2
Activo
2024-09-20


Document3
Vencido
2024-09-20


Document4
Vencido
2024-08-01


Document5
Rescindido
2024-08-11



What I need the query returns is the correct order of the dates inside each status, for example:



Title
Status
Expiration Date




Document2
Activo
2024-09-20


Document1
Activo
2024-10-13


Document4
Vencido
2024-08-01


Document3
Vencido
2024-09-20


Document5
Rescindido
2024-08-11



I need the query result to be passed to the paginator.
Thank you
